# VB.NET Find group membership for user recursively (indirectly)

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I am using the below code to get the groups a specific user is a member of directly

```
    Public Function IsInGroup(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Collection
    Dim Groups As New Collection
    Dim domain = "registry"
    Dim dirEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & domain, username, password, DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
    Dim dirSearcher As New DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
    dirSearcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")"
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf")
    Dim propCount As Integer
    Try
        Dim dirSearchResults As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
        propCount = dirSearchResults.Properties("memberOf").Count
        Dim dn As String
        Dim equalsIndex As String
        Dim commaIndex As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To propCount - 1
            dn = dirSearchResults.Properties("memberOf")(i)
            equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1)
            commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1)
            If equalsIndex = -1 Then
                Return Nothing
            End If
            If Not Groups.Contains(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1)) Then
                Groups.Add(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1))
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.GetType Is GetType(System.NullReferenceException) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Selected user isn't a member of any groups at this time.", "No groups listed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            'they are still a good user just does not
            'have a "memberOf" attribute so it errors out.
            'code to do something else here if you want
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString, "Search Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Try
    'Console.WriteLine(Groups)
    Return Groups

End Function
```

But how do I get the groups that the user is a member of InDirectly ?

ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than querying and enumerating recursive group membership yourself you should have Active Directory do this for you by querying the [tokenGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680275(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute.

The tokenGroups attribute is an array of SIDs computed by Active Directory and is used to verify user access.

We need to translate these SIDs to their sAMAccountNames to get the actual group names.

In unmanaged code this could be accomplished by calling the [DsCrackNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675970(VS.85).aspx) API or the [IADsNameTranslate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706046(v=VS.85).aspx) interface.

In (VB).NET the easiest way is to use the UserPrincipal class (requires .NET Framework 3.5 or higher) which exposes the [GetAuthorizationGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

See https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2011/01/18/recursive-group-membership-in-powershell/ for an example. It's in PowerShell but trivial to translate to VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks for that - I will have a look, if tokenGroups are quicker and better then sounds good to me :)